# How do I resolve this Tableau Error: "no declaration found for element 'simple-id'"?

Tags: tableau-api

When I send a .twbx package to someone with tableau 2018.3, I have the below error in Tableau 2019. Is there someway that I can make the "simple-id" element declared or what do I do?

`Unable to complete action
Errors occurred while trying to load the workbook "C:\Users\fake.user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.Outlook\06BDO9C2\Dashboard.twbx". The load was not able to complete successfully.
Error(571,66): no declaration found for element 'simple-id' (id: C:\Users\FAKEUSER\AppData\Local\Temp\TableauTemp\1241239161\Dashboard.twb)
Error(571,66): attribute 'uuid' is not declared for element 'simple-id' (id: C:\Users\FAKEUSER\AppData\Local\Temp\TableauTemp\1241239161\Dashboard.twb)`

I have tried saving this in version 2018.3 and it did not work.

I would like for my coworker to be able to open the file without having that error and having to change their version of the software.

Answer (score 0):

what a confusing error! The workbook was made with a newer version of Tableau, so if you install the latest, you should be able to open it and re-save with whatever version you want.